# How do I access this element in C# using Selenium?

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the following element and enter text into it. I have tried a number of different ways to access the element but always get the same error. My current line of code

```
searchTerm = driver.FindElement(By.Id("keyword"));
```

generates the same error

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"keyword"}

The element, shown below, clearly has the Id 'keyword'.

```html
<input maxlength="100" size="20" value="" name="keyword" id="keyword" title="keyword" class="FORMshrt2">
```

I used firebug to capture the complete XPath for this element.

> /html/body/div/span/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[1]/span/form/div[3]/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/span/input

How do I access this element?

Comment: I need to add that adding a wait period is not the answer. I have stepped through the program and waited until the page is completely loaded and I have verified manually that the element exists. I still cannot get the program to find this element. I also know that there are iframes on the page, but changing which iframe I am referencing doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Is this element visible on the page? Selenium will only interact with visible elements by design.

Comment: Check if your element is within an iframe. If it is, try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652932/2285470

Answer (score 0):

Try closing tag input with `/>` like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232121/closing-html-input-tag-issue/13232170#13232170).

`<input maxlength="100" size="20" value="" name="keyword" id="keyword" title="keyword" class="FORMshrt2" />`

I don't know if Selenium expects this closing tag, but everything else look ok.

Answer (score 0):

The element might not have appeared at the moment you've started looking for it. Wait for the element to [become present](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15142611/771848) in the DOM:

```
IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id("keyword"))));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use wait statement then try the below code

you can just try the following code, which may help for your case,

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='FORMshrt2']")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='FORMshrt2']")).SendKeys("your text");
```

By using your class name i'm identifying the element, first clicking on it and then passing the string.

Comment: Tried this and got the same result;
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='FORMshrt2']"}