# How to locate and click on an element which is nested within multiple frame and frameset through Selenium using Webdriver and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, frame

I have html page like below and I need to click on Login inside the class clslogin.

How do I traverse to find the Login.
I'm using C# with selenium Webdriver.

With XPath (/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a)  I'm not getting control on Login class, always element not found error is throwing. Can anybody help me to get exact xpath.

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <frameset name="mytestTopFrame" rows="*"......  >
  <frame name="mytestTopsubframe" src="index.html" width="100%"......... >
   <html>
    <head></head>
     <frameset name="mytest" rows="70,20..."......  >
       <frame name="mytestsubframe" src="menu.html" width="100%"......... >
       <html>
        <body class="clsmenu" .......>
         <div align="left">
           <table id="Title" ......>
            <tbody>
             <tr class="toptitle" ...>
              <td class="clicklogin" ....>
               <a class="clslogin" href="linkref">Login </a>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
         </div>
        </body>
       </html>
      </frame>
    </frameset>
   </html>
  </frame>
 </frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the element with text as **Login** you have to induce *WebDriverwait* twice to switch through 2 child `frame` and then again to locate the desired element as follows:

```
//SwitchTo mytestTopsubframe
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.Name("mytestTopsubframe")));
//SwitchTo mytestsubframe
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.Name("mytestsubframe")));
//Locate the desired element
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[@class='clslogin' and @href='linkref']"))).Click();
```

**Note**: You don't have to consider the presence of `<frameset>` and can safely ignore those tags.

Comment: Still not able to get to Login. For each frame me getting 'No such frames' error. Is it an issue with browser bcz  I'm using Firefox current latest version 'Quantum'.

Comment: Sorry, I was not setting to DefaultContent() before switching to frames.
Thanks it worked for me. +1

Comment: Another update. above code working only on IE11 version-11.492.
'Nosuchframe' exception on Firefox, Chrome latest versions. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first change to the correct iframe to access the path who are below the iframe. For that you can use `driver.SwichtTo().Frame("your frame ID")`. If this solution does not work, in this thread [may be a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762116/how-to-select-iframe-in-selenium) the thread uses the same lines of code but it search for the parent and child nodes

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have "id" attribute in frameset.  Instead I have "name" attribute, from which I still not getting control to go inside the frame. I used By.Name("mytestTopFrame") to switch to the frame. Is it possible to switch to frame using "name" attribute ?

Comment: Yep, it uses "By", you can use it with xpath, name, id or whatever you need.