# Identifying element from nested HTML code under frame using Selenium (confirmed no iframe)

Tags: python, css, selenium, frame, webdriverwait

I am learning Selenium using python and was trying to automate form filling in some website.

However, I am unable to identify any element under a frame and it gave me `NoSuchElementException` error. I have tried using different `find_element` function e.g. CSS, XPATH (pretty sure the XPATH is correct as i copied it from Firebug) and also tried to include explicit wait using `WebDriverWait`. However, nothing came through.

The command I have tried before:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("testFormNumForLastAttempt"); 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text' and @name='testFormNumForLastAttempt']");

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "testFormNumForLastAttempt")));
```

I was trying to switch to another frame

```
    driver.switch_to.frame("main")
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    NoSuchFrameException: Message: No frame found
```

I have extracted the relevant HTML code below and was looking for solution to identify the `testFormNumForLastAttempt` input parameter.

Thanks in advance. Any help will be much appreciate.

```html
<html>

<frameset rows="0,0,*" frameborder="no" border="0">

  <frame name="applet_container" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize src="">
    <frame name="javascript_container" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize src="/repoes/td-es-app517/RETJSContainer_WOC.do?__AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST_PARAMETER_MECHANISM__=applet">
      <frame name="main" scrolling="yes" noresize src="/repoes/td-es-app517/Loading.do" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0">

        <html>

        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
          <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
          <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">


          <div id="authByTestForm">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Test Form No. for Last Attempt <span class="star">*</span> </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="8" name="testFormNumForLastAttempt" id="testFormNumForLastAttempt" value="" class="uppercase" autocomplete="off">

                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top">Date of Birth <span class="star">*</span></td>
                  <td>
                    <table class="example_table">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="7">
                            <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" id="testFormBirthYear" name="testFormBirthYear" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,'testFormBirthMonth')" value="" autocomplete="off"> Year

                            <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" id="testFormBirthMonth" name="testFormBirthMonth" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,'testFormBirthDay')" value="" autocomplete="off"> Month

                            <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" id="testFormBirthDay" name="testFormBirthDay" value="" autocomplete="off"> Day

                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Example:</td>
                          <td class="example_cell">1995</td>
                          <td>Year</td>
                          <td class="example_cell">09</td>
                          <td>Month</td>
                          <td class="example_cell">08</td>
                          <td>Day</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: you may have to switch to external frame, next switch to middle frame, and finally switch to inner frame - [Python Selenium Webdriver - Navigating nested frame sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732549/python-selenium-webdriver-navigating-nested-frame-sets)

Comment: Thanks. I resolved it by adding  `driver.switch_to.default_content(); ` first and followed by switching to external, middle and finally the main frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` tag with `id` as **testFormNumForLastAttempt** seems to be nested within 3 layers of `<frame>`.

So to `click()` within the element you have to:

- Ignore (safely) the presence of *parent* or *child* `<frameset>` tags.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the first layer of `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the second layer of _`frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the third layer of `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"applet_container")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='javascript_container'][src$='__AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST_PARAMETER_MECHANISM__=applet']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='main' and contains(@src, 'Loading')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#testFormNumForLastAttempt[name='testFormNumForLastAttempt']"))).click()
    ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to locate and click on an element which is nested within multiple frame and frameset through Selenium using Webdriver and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798937/how-to-locate-and-click-on-an-element-which-is-nested-within-multiple-frame-and/50813825#50813825)

---

### Outro

- [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)

Comment: Thanks. I resolved it by adding  `driver.switch_to.default_content(); ` first and followed by switching to external, middle and finally the main frame.