# Spinner clear value exception in Selenium c# Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to test this popup window:

[image]

but for spinner I get exception. I tried these codes but non of them worked.

```
Actions componentProportion = new Actions(driver);
componentProportion.SendKesy(Kesy.Control+"a");
componentProportion.SendKeys(editNumber,"2356").Build().Perform();
```

When I run this code nothing happens and it also causes problem for new text box(Display Title)  code and it doesn't work properly.

```
//Edit display title
IWebElement editDt = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='cmp_display_title']"));
editDt.Click();
Thread.Sleep(500);
editDt.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
editDt.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
Thread.Sleep(500);
editDt.SendKeys("hello");
```

And if I want to use this code:

```
IWebElement editNumber = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("something"));
editNumber.Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
editNumber.SendKeys(Keys.Control+"a");
```

I get this exception:

> ElementVisibleException : element not visible

Is there anyway to solve this problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the popup part of iframe?

Comment: @AntonAngelov Yes It is. In that frame there is Edit button for each component. after clicking on it this popup appears.

Answer (score 0):

So, since your elements are in frame, in order to be able to work with them you need to switch to that frame first (usually by name)

```
//Switch to required frame
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ContentContainer");

// find your elements and do the actions

// This is how you switch to the default page
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Answer (score -1):

As I noticed, you want to replace the display title input text with some new text

In order to clear the text, you dont need to simuale ctrl+a.

Simply, use this code to set new value to your text element :

```
IWebElement editDt = driver.FindElementById("cmp_display_title");
editDt.SendKeys(""); // clears the text
editDt.SendKeys("your new text");
```

Comment: This one doesn't work. ElementVisibleException : element not visible

Comment: You may need find the iframe first, and then switch to that.
This may help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607964/selenium-unable-to-access-iframe-and-data-inside-it