# selenium xpath, select span with specific title

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select this element using chromedriver selenium:

```
<span title="1968milziewa@ama-coupons.com" class="rcmContactAddress">1968milziewa@ama-coupons.com</span>
```

where the email address is a variable.

Tried this, but doesn't work:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='" + username + "@ama-coupons.com']")).Click();
```

also tried this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@title, '"+username+"@ama-coupons.com']")).Click();
```

but it doesn't work either. #1 gives element not found #2 gives not a valid xpath selector.

UPDATE:

I had it work with a hard-coded email address, however, as soon as I replace that email address with a variable, it doesn't work anymore.

HTML Element:

```
<span title="1959jessamin@ama-coupons.com" class="rcmContactAddress">1959jessamin@ama-coupons.com</span>
```

code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("span[title='"+email+"']"))).Click(); Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Error: (which also shows the value of email:)

> Inner Exception 1:
>       NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span[title='1959Jessamin@ama-coupons.com']"}
>         (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem with your second selector you forgot `)` inside selector:

```
By.XPath("//span[contains(@title, '1968milziewa@ama-coupons.com')]")
```

For `element not found` error use wait, here code with explicit wait until element is clickable:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("span[title='1968milziewa@ama-coupons.com']"))).Click();
```

For more information about waits you can find in [Selenium Docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) or 
[When to use explicit wait vs implicit wait in Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404160/when-to-use-explicit-wait-vs-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver)

If element is inside iframe [Selenium: Unable to access iframe and data inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607964/selenium-unable-to-access-iframe-and-data-inside-it)

Selectors be used as well:

```
By.CssSelector("span[title='1968milziewa@ama-coupons.com']")
By.XPath("//span[.='1968milziewa@ama-coupons.com']")
```